# Fault in proof of $\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta

Consider the proof of:  $$\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^{2}}{6}$$

So the proof assume that (because of Euler decomposition) $$\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = \prod_{n > 0}\left(1 - \frac{x^{2}}{(n\pi)^{2}}\right)$$

Why should we consider the $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$, that $\sin(x)$ has the same decomposition?

Please tell me where's my fault.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2?lq=1

Comment: The infinite product is equal to $1$ if $x = 0$, but $\sin 0 = 0$.

Comment: Why should $\sin x$ have the same decomposition?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang but $x=0$, then $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ does not exist and its limit is equal to $1$.

Comment: @egreg yes, that's my fault.
And I forgot about Teylor's sum.

Comment: @kamil09875: If you're going to treat $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ as undefined at $0$ rather than considering the analytic (convergent power series) extension, then the OP's equation doesn't make sense at all. I was merely pointing out why the infinite product cannot be equal to $\sin x$.